# How to use Where clause with if else conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a projects table where list of all projects and project suggestions are stored. if suggestions are accepted then they become projects too.

```
id  p_name  suggestion accepted
1   abc      0         pending
2   fgh      1         pending
3   aec      1         yes
4   etc      1         pending
```

now I want a query that should show the following rows only.

```
id  p_name  suggestion accepted
1   abc      0         pending
2   aec      1         yes
```

it is something like this

> select * from table  if('suggestion'== 1)then get only
>   where('accepted','yes') otherwise get only those rows which have
>   suggestion == 0

Comment: `WHERE (suggestion = 1 AND accepted = 'yes') OR suggestion = 0 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This?

```
select
    *
from
    "table" t
where
    t.suggestion = 0
    or
    ( t.suggestion = 1 and t.accepted = 'yes' )
```